# How do I make a makefile for creating a library and output file?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I want to make a library file in lib and output file in bin directory.
But my makefile does not work.

my directory tree
~/home$ tree

```
.
├── bin
├── include
│   └── myhead.h
├── lib
├── libsrc
│   └── myfunc.c
└── src
    ├── Makefile
    └── main.c
```

Here is my makefile

```
.SUFFIXES = .c .o
.c.o :
        $(CC) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) $<


CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -c
AR = ar
OBJECTS = main.o
SRCS = main.c

LIB_TARGET = ../lib/libmyfunc.a
LIB_OBJS = ../libsrc/myfunc.o
LIB_SRCS = ../libsrc/myfunc.c

LIBS = -lmyfunc
LIB_DIR = -L../lib

$(LIB_TARGET) : $(LIB_OBJS)
        $(AR) -rcv  $(LIB_TARGET) $(LIB_OBJS)

INC = -I../include

TARGET = ../bin/main

$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIB_DIR) $(LIBS)

clean :
        rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET) core
```

I think it works but it does not work.
I get an ar: ../libsrc/myfunc.o: No such file or directory error
and myfunc.o file created in src directory.

I want to get files like

```
.
├── bin
│   └── main.out    <-- new
├── include
│   └── myhead.h
├── lib
│   └── libmyfunc.a  <-- new
├── libsrc
│   └── myfunc.c
│   └── myfunc.o    <-- new
└── src
    ├── Makefile
    └── main.c
```

---

Edit:

My build log

```
~/home/src$ make
gcc -I../include -g -c ../libsrc/myfunc.c
ar -rcv  ../lib/libmyfunc.a ../libsrc/myfunc.o
ar: ../libsrc/myfunc.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:20: ../lib/libmyfunc.a] Error 1
```

Tree after building
~/home$ tree

```
.
├── bin
├── include
│   └── myhead.h
├── lib
├── libsrc
│   └── myfunc.c
└── src
    ├── Makefile
    ├── main.c
    └── myfunc.o
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem? What is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: the easiest way is: use cmake instead. It is designed for humans.

Comment: "does not work" is never a good problem description. Please provide the expected result vs actual result. Also provide the full build log.

Comment: I set the route for object file of archive file in my makefile but
I get an ar: ../libsrc/myfunc.o: No such file or directory error and myfunc object file created in src directory.

Comment: Repeat: Show your build log. Also show your actual directory tree after building.

Comment: Check [my](https://github.com/incoder1/IO/blob/master/Makefile-unix-shared) it is also using several source directories. You can simply copy-paste end edit locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this forum eats <kbd>Tab</kbd> indentation, so if you copy-paste the below Makefiles, do fix the indentation using e.g. `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile` .

I would use

```makefile
LIBSRC  := libsrc
LIBDIR  := lib
BINSRC  := src
BINDIR  := bin
INCDIR  := include
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDFLAGS :=
TARGETS := $(BINDIR)/main.out $(LIBDIR)/libmyfunc.a
LIBOBJS := $(LIBSRC)/myfunc.o

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
        rm -f $(TARGETS) $(BINSRC)/*.o $(LIBSRC)/*.o

$(LIBSRC)/%.o: $(LIBSRC)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $(LDFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(BINSRC)/%.o: $(BINSRC)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $(LDFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(LIBDIR)/libmyfunc.a: $(LIBOBJS)
        $(AR) -rcv $@ $^

$(BINDIR)/main.out: $(BINSRC)/main.o $(LIBDIR)/libmyfunc.a
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)/ $(BINSRC)/main.o $(LDFLAGS) -L$(LIBDIR) -lmyfunc -o $@
```

Or, if you prefer to put temporary object files into a separate directory, say build/, then

```makefile
CC       := gcc
CFLAGS   := -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDFLAGS  :=

BUILDDIR := build

INCDIR   := include
SRCDIR   := src
BINDIR   := bin
LIBDIR   := lib

MAINOBJS := $(BUILDDIR)/main.o
LIBOBJS  := $(BUILDDIR)/myfunc.o
TARGETS  := $(BINDIR)/main $(LIBDIR)/libmyfunc.a

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
        rm -f $(TARGETS) $(MAINOBJS) $(LIBOBJS) $(BUILDDIR)/*

$(LIBDIR)/libmyfunc.a: $(LIBOBJS)
        $(AR) -rcv $@ $(LIBOBJS)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) -c $^ -o $@

$(BINDIR)/main: $(MAINOBJS) $(LIBDIR)/libmyfunc.a
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) $(MAINOBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -L$(LIBDIR) -lmyfunc -o $@
```

This has the benefit of keeping the source directory unchanged.